# ext4 Recovery from known file sizes

Tags: data-recovery, ext4

I'm using PhotoRec to recover files on an ext4 volume.  Long story short, I canceled a resize a few seconds into it.  Nothing was written to the disk but a new partition table.  Nothing has worked towards bringing anything back.  A few files are getting recovered.  I have a list of every file that was there, and how big they were down to the exact byte.  Is there any utility to just dump the raw data into new files on another partition, based on offsets from successfully recovered files?  Nothing was fragmented, as well.  I had just copied them from elsewhere, so they were all contiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I get you right, but if you want to recover the raw_files and you know each offset (start_of_datablock - end_of_datablock) within the old filessystem and you're sure there is nothing fragmented, you could simply use dd to copy it back. As an example. Lets assume you have a Picture.jpg file starting at fs-block 12000 and ending at 12060, and your fs-block-size is the default of ext4 = 4096bytes):

```
    dd if=/dev/sdxold of=/home/whatever/Picture.jpg bs=4096 skip=12000 count=61 conv=noerror,sync
```

That should bring your jpeg file back for example. You could do this now with every file if you know the exact start and end-offsets.

-> If you don't know them and your filesystem has been deleted, because your partition has been deleted. You could either try to recover your filesystems metainfo (=inodes from the inode tables) by doing a string search on the device:

```
    strings /dev/sdxold
```

and then manually recovering the different inodes of your previous filesystem. If you have them recovered you can search for the datablocks addressed by them and recover them with the above method.
-> This means a lot of work and I don't know if there is a tool out there, capable of doing that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out scalpel, it's good at finding files, especially .jpg and such.